# Unable to create sns from an autoscaling hook with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, terraform, autoscaling

Below terraform script should make sns topic for autoscaling group one bastion host and send notification when a host comes up or goes down.

The security group:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ssh_from_authorised_ips" {

          name = "ssh_from_authorised_ips"
          description = "SSH from authorised ip addresses for adminstering bastion host"
          vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"

          ingress {
            from_port = 22
            to_port = 22
            protocol = "tcp"
            cidr_blocks = ["192.xx.xx.xx.xx/32", "62.xx.xx.xx/32"]
          }

          egress {
            from_port = 0
            to_port = 0
            protocol = "tcp"
            cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
          }
          egress {
            from_port = 0
            to_port = 65535
            protocol = "udp"
            cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
          }

          tags {
            Name = "ssh_from_authorised_ips"
            "om:account_type" = "${var.tag_om_account_type}"
            "om:env" = "${var.tag_om_env}"
            "om:cost_center" = "network"
          }
        }
```

The bastion script:

```
data "aws_ami" "bastion_ami" {
      most_recent = true

      filter {
        name = "name"
        values = ["testami_*"]
      }

      owners = ["self"]
    }

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "bastion_asg" {

  lifecycle { create_before_destroy = true }

  vpc_zone_identifier  = ["${split(",", var.public_subnets)}"]

  name = "asg_${aws_launch_configuration.bastion_lc.name}"
  min_size = "1"
  max_size = "1"

  default_cooldown = "180"
  health_check_grace_period = "180"
  health_check_type = "EC2"
  launch_configuration = "${aws_launch_configuration.bastion_lc.id}"

  tags = [
    {
      key = "Name"
      value = "bastion"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
    {
      key = "om:account_type"
      value = "${var.tag_om_account_type}"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    }
  ]
}

resource "aws_sns_topic" "bastion_updates" {
  name = "bastion-updates-topic"
  display_name = "Bastion_notification"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "bastion_key" {
  key_name   =  "bastion_key_name"
  public_key = "${file("/home/xxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa_bastion.pub")}"
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "bastion_lc" {

  lifecycle { create_before_destroy = true }

  name_prefix = "bastion_"
  image_id = "${data.aws_ami.bastion_ami.id}"
  instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  security_groups = ["${split(",", var.security_groups)}"]

  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.bastion_key.key_name}"

  root_block_device {
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = "${var.volume_size}"
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

}


resource "aws_iam_role" "bastion_notify_role" {
  name = "bastion_notify_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_lifecycle_hook" "bastion_down_notify" {
 name                   = "bastion-down"
 autoscaling_group_name = "${aws_autoscaling_group.bastion_asg.name}"
 default_result         = "CONTINUE"
 heartbeat_timeout      = 31
 lifecycle_transition   = "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING"
 notification_metadata = <<EOF
{
 "bastion_message": "Bastion going down."
}
EOF
  notification_target_arn = "${aws_sns_topic.bastion_updates.arn}"
  role_arn                = "${aws_iam_role.bastion_notify_role.arn}"
}


resource "aws_autoscaling_lifecycle_hook" "bastion_up_notify" {
 name                   = "bastion-up"
 autoscaling_group_name = "${aws_autoscaling_group.bastion_asg.name}"
 default_result         = "CONTINUE"
 heartbeat_timeout      = 31
 lifecycle_transition   = "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING"
 notification_metadata = <<EOF
{
 "bastion_message": "Bastion coming up."
}
EOF
  notification_target_arn = "${aws_sns_topic.bastion_updates.arn}"
  role_arn                = "${aws_iam_role.bastion_notify_role.arn}"
}




----------------------------------------------
```

I get the following error when I do terraform apply -target=bastion_host.

```
module.bastion_host.aws_autoscaling_lifecycle_hook.bastion_down_notify: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_autoscaling_lifecycle_hook.bastion_down_notify: [DEBUG] Retrying AWS AutoScaling Lifecycle Hook: ValidationError: Unable to publish test message to notification target arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:031768xxxx:bastion-updates-topic using IAM role arn:aws:iam::0317682xxxxx:role/bastion_notify_role. Please check your target and role configuration and try to put lifecycle hook again.
        status code: 400, request id: ad7379a6-09ca-11e8-85a3-d114xxxxxx
* module.bastion_host.aws_autoscaling_lifecycle_hook.bastion_up_notify: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_autoscaling_lifecycle_hook.bastion_up_notify: [DEBUG] Retrying AWS AutoScaling Lifecycle Hook: ValidationError: Unable to publish test message to notification target arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:03176821xxxx:bastion-updates-topic using IAM role arn:aws:iam::0317682xxx:role/bastion_notify_role. Please check your target and role configuration and try to put lifecycle hook again.
        status code: 400, request id: ad7e4f1a-09ca-11e8-ac2b-2bxxxx
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a policy attached to the `bastion_notify_role` role allowing it to publish to SNS. There is an AWS managed policy for this:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "bastion_notify_sns_access" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.bastion_notify_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AutoScalingNotificationAccessRole"
}
```